# How to read position of each item of recyclerview in android studio 3.6 without clicking on itemview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have done above problem using **setOnItemClickListener** but i want solution without clicked on itemview.

code of setOnItemClickListener

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new PostCropListBuyerAdapter.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position)
            {
                View itemView =                 
                recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView;
                TextView t = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewPostCropNameBuyer);
            }


        });
```

Adapter class in which there are 7 textviw and one button view. i want when save button is click by user then the name of button must be change and permanently.

**PostCropListBuyerAdapter**

```
public class PostCropListBuyerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostCropListBuyerAdapter.PRSListViewHolder>
{
    private List<PostCropBuyerInfo> postCropList;

    public PostCropListBuyerAdapter(List<PostCropBuyerInfo> postCropList)
    {
        this.postCropList = postCropList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PRSListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_crop_list_buyer,parent,false);
        return new PRSListViewHolder(view, mListener);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PRSListViewHolder holder, int position)
    {

        PostCropBuyerInfo postCropData = postCropList.get(position);

        holder.textViewname.setText("Crop Name : "+postCropData.getName());
        holder.textViewquantity.setText("Quantity : "+postCropData.getQuantity());
        holder.textViewrate.setText("Rate : "+postCropData.getRate());
        holder.textViewdescription.setText("Description : "+postCropData.getDescription());
        holder.textViewtime.setText("Time : "+postCropData.getTime()+" months");
        holder.textViewbuyername.setText("Consumer Name : "+postCropData.getBuyername());
        holder.textViewbuyernumber.setText("Consumer Number : "+postCropData.getBuyernumber());
        holder.buttonSaveToList.setText(postCropData.getButtonName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return postCropList.size();
    }


    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener
    {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener)
    {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class PRSListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView textViewname;
        TextView textViewquantity;
        TextView textViewrate;
        TextView textViewdescription;
        TextView textViewtime;
        TextView textViewbuyername;
        TextView textViewbuyernumber;
        Button buttonSaveToList;
        Button buttonSavedSuccessfully;


        public PRSListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener)
        {
            super(itemView);
itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewPostCropIdBuyer);
            textViewname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewPostCropNameBuyer);
            textViewquantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewPostCropQuantityBuyer);
            textViewrate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewPostCropRateBuyer);
            textViewdescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewPostCropDesriptionBuyer);
            textViewtime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewPostCropTimeBuyer);
            textViewbuyername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewPostBuyerNameBuyer);
            textViewbuyernumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewPostBuyerNumberBuyer);
            buttonSaveToList = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idButtonPostSaveToListButtonBuyer);
            buttonSavedSuccessfully = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idButtonPostSavedSuccessfullyButtonBuyer);



            buttonSaveToList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if(listener != null)
                    {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();

                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                        {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an array list and also an int value in your RecyclerView class:

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
int i=0;
```

Now change the part you insert data in TextViews and Buttons Like this:

```
    data.add("Crop Name : "+postCropData.getName());
    holder.textViewname.setText(data.get(i));
    i++;
    data.add("Quantity : "+postCropData.getQuantity());
    holder.textViewquantity.setText(data.get(i));
    i++;
    data.add("Rate : "+postCropData.getRate());
    holder.textViewrate.setText(data.get(i));
    i++;
    data.add("Description : "+postCropData.getDescription());
    holder.textViewdescription.setText(data.get(i));
    i++;
    data.add("Time : "+postCropData.getTime()+" months");
    holder.textViewtime.setText(data.get(i));
    i++;
    data.add("Consumer Name : "+postCropData.getBuyername());
    holder.textViewbuyername.setText(data.get(i));
    i++;
    data.add("Consumer Number : "+postCropData.getBuyernumber());
    holder.textViewbuyernumber.setText(data.get(i));
    i++;
    data.add(postCropData.getButtonName());
    holder.buttonSaveToList.setText(data.get(i));
    i++;
```

ok.Now for example you want to change first Textview of third item.number of data item for that text view is 17.so you do this to change it:

```
data.set(17,String New Value);
adapter.notifyItemChanged(3);
```

New Value is the string value you want to set.17 is the data item number for the specific TextView and adapter is your RecyclerView adapter.

Comment: using your answer i got data of that particular position, but i don't want data i want that view for changing dynamically. e.g. in my xml file i used 7 TextView and 1 Button i want to read this Textview and Button without clicking on any event listener.

Comment: So each of your RecyclerView item has 7 TextViews and 1 Button right?

Comment: yes, and i want to read that TextView and Button without user interaction in activity

Comment: I updated my answer check it and comment me if you need more help :)

Comment: Sir, your answer not solve my issue, I just want how to read positions of recyclerview and on that particular position read all textView and button. I want to update that button. this things must be happen without user interaction

Comment: I actually understand what do u want.Textviews must get their values from an ArrayList in RecyclerView class and then you must change the value of the array list and use notify change to change the TextView value.

Comment: but, how to change button text?

Comment: Like TextViews use a separate ArrayList for their texts.

Comment: Sir, in position there are 8 view i.e. 7 textview and one button view. How to read views in particular position and set value permanently?

Comment: put ur recyclerview class in question plz and i will give u a code sample.

Comment: check answer again.